# Compile UWSGI Emperor_mongodb plugin

Tags: python, mongodb, uwsgi

I'm currently playing with uWSGI and trying to store the vassals configuration into my MongoDB.

however, I'm not able to launch an instance of uWSGI using the emperor_mongodb plugin.

Regarding the obvious error message, the emperor_mongodb is missing  (and it is, I've checked it), so I try to compile it using the uWSGI method, but I'm facing a problem which is directly related to my lack of skill on it.

Error Message:

```
[root@PRDUCE01 uwsgi]# ./uwsgi --plugin emperor_mongodb --emperor "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27107,emperor.vassals"
open("./emperor_mongodb_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 4755]
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./emperor_mongodb_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
*** Starting uWSGI 1.4.5 (64bit) on [Thu Jan 31 16:15:36 2013] ***
```

So, could you help me to build it?

Here is what's I want to use:

```
 python uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/emperor_mongodb package emperor
```

I know that the package argument is the ini file stored on /plugins/emperor.ini, BUT I don't really know what to put on my file exept those lines:

```
[uwsgi]
    main_plugin = emperor
    inherit = base
    bin_name = emperor_mongodb_plugin.so
    as_shared_library = true
```

But it doesn't seems to be working:

```
python uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/emperor_mongodb package emperor_mongo using profile: buildconf/package.ini

detected include path: ['/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/include', '/usr/include']

*** uWSGI building and linking plugin plugins/emperor_mongodb ***

[gcc -pthread] /usr/lib/uwsgi/emperor_mongo_plugin.so
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

*** unable to build emperor_mongo plugin ***
```

So, if you have any clue about how to compile as a plugin this feature, I'll be happy !D

Answer (score 1):

python uwsgiconfig.py --plugin plugins/emperor_mongodb/

(be sure to have mongodb-dev package on debian/ubuntu)

Comment: Unfortunatly, I'm under CentOS and there is no package like this.

When I try your command line, I've got the exactly same error.

Comment: So I found that my VM was not installed with GCC-C++, and after the installation, the command is running fine, but fail to compile emperor_mongodb_plugin.so because mongoDB Headers are missing.

I'm under CentOS 6.3, and I got a 10Gen.repo which is able to find the RPM for MongoDB Server/Client binaries but no trace of any headers.

Do you know where can I find them? Or, do you know the Yum/rpm command which allow me to extract only headers from RPM Sources?

Comment: I finally decide to rebuild my environnement upon a Debian 6.0.6 Inet distribution, unfortunatly even if I install the required Mongodb-dev package, the installation fail and throw me the following error message:

http://pastebin.com/cLzZCSQb

Comment: I'm guessing the versions differ from what you installed to what emperor_mongodb_plugin expects.

Comment: Hello @Ross and thanks for your hint ;-)
Indeed, the libboost1.42-dev was not installed and required.
But NOW, I'm still facing another problem coming from the dbclient?h header containing some base classes.

Indeed, I installed the mongodb-dev package available on the debian/main repository, but this one do not seems to contain the right header because uWSGI is looking for a member "setSoTimeout" which is not implement at all on the dbclient.h/ mongo::DBClientConnection class.
Do you know if uWSGI require a more recent file source?

Comment: hmm - not making it easy for you.  I'd ping the uwsgi mailing list - might be quicker for you.